# type object 'pmdarima.arima._arima.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__' I am getting this error. Anyone knows how to solve this in python

Tags: cython

type object 'pmdarima.arima._arima.array' has no attribute '**reduce_cython**'

I am getting the above error. Please anyone knows how to solve it.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: FWIW, I'm having the same problem when trying to use pmdarima via anaconda/jumpyter. Have updated numpy 1.15.4->1.16.3, scipy (1.1.0->1.2.1) in trying to get through the run of module errors before landing on this error message with doesn't seem to have a fix. I suspect it has to do with the version of cpython pmdarima was built with.

Comment: i am also facing same issue, tried everyhing. I believe the issue is because i am using Python 3.7 and the support is available till 3.6 version only.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your numpy and scipy to the latest versions.

source: [AttributeError: type object 'pmdarima.arima._arima.array' has no attribute '**reduce_cython**'](https://github.com/tgsmith61591/pmdarima/issues/144)